# How to disable F9=Search in Dell wired keyboard KB216t (Windows 7)

Tags: windows-7, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts

I recently got a Dell KB216 wired keyboard, and for some reason the F9 key seems to be linked to the "windows search" function, preventing applications to use it.

For instance, in Matlab I would normally press F9 to run the selected code, but now it launches the "windows search"!. This doesn't happen with my old keyboard. I do see that in the new keyboard there is the icon of a magnifying glass colored in blue, which makes me thing that this should be the functionality when pressing simultaneously the "Fn" key (which I'm not doing). How can I disable / correct this? I tried searching for drivers in Dell site but found nothing.

Thanks, Jorge.

Comment: Have you looked in the keyboard manual?

Comment: Some laptops - for reasons only known to the manufacturers - have the FN functions as default. That means if you want "F9" you actually have to press "FN+F9". This setting can be changed in BIOS/UEFI.

Comment: @DavidPostill: I have no manual, and none seems to be found online :(

Comment: @MichaelBay: Thanks for the suggestion, but it really seems it's something wrong with the keyboard: it doesn't matter what combinations of F9 I use (just F9, with CRTL, with FN, with ALT), the windows search is always launched! BTW, I'm on a PC and F9 works fine with other keyboards.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Don't panic.

the Dell KB216, as well as Dell laptop keyboards, come with the feature of locking the <kbd>Fn</kbd> key by using the <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd> hotkey combination.

[image: Fn lock key]

If you've switched on <kbd>Fn</kbd> locking, all keypresses are interpreted as if you were holding the <kbd>Fn</kbd> key at the time. The keyboard itself will not be saving the Fn lock state across reboots and unplugs.

To release a previously issued <kbd>Fn</kbd> lock, just hit <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd> once.

Comment: Thank you so much, syneticon-dj! That was the actual problem!

Comment: But you haven't had to wait for over 4 months to get it resolved, right?

Comment: Thankfully not :) (things probably went back to normal after the next reboot, but I really don't recall when I stopped noticing the "faulty behavior"). Honestly, I had totally forgotten about it until your post arrived! Thanks anyway for the answer!